# PostgreSQL installation fails with macOS Big Sur(M1)

Tags: postgresql, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I am struggling to install PostgreSQL on my macOS Big Sur with M1 chip.
These are the message I get when I try to install PostgreSQL in the last step. I tried installing version 12, 11, 10. Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

- A non-fatal error occur whilst creating menu shortcuts.
- Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly
  Failed to start the database server.

Comment: I don't have M1 chip yet, and sorry to hear that happens. I wonder, if you would use this for local development, could you instead use postgresApp (maybe that works?). https://postgresapp.com/

Comment: I'm getting the same problem in Big Sur on a mid-2015 Macbook Pro.  Postgres 12 ran on my Mac fine, and I'm kicking myself for uninstalling it before installing 13.  Figured out anything yet?

Comment: @CetinBasoz I tried the app and it worked fine, but because I had to install PostgreSQL and pgAdmin for the class using purpose, I couldn't convince the teaching staffs with this. But thank you so much for the suggestion and sorry for the late reply!

Comment: @workerjoe Well I can't say that mine works perfectly yet but what I did seems to work fine so far at least. So one of the things I did is: to download PostgreSQL without "pgAdmin" from the PostgreSQL installer, and then I downloaded the newest pgAdmin separately. I don't know if you have the same problem as me but hopefully this help you somehow.

Comment: @Penguin I went with postgres.app but I hate having to do it.  Eventually there'll be a bug with that one, too...

Comment: @Penguin, I see. I am not a fan of pgAdmin since version 4. 3 was nice.

Comment: I’m running into the same issue. I tried installing PGadmin separately but still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 4):

There is a permissions issue produced by Big Sur sec policies. https://pgsnake.blogspot.com/2020/11/macos-big-sur-upgrade-breaking.html

This will happen if you're installing in the default location, which in this case is Library. I was struggling with this for a few days and found that if I define my own installation path not located in the Library folder(say some folder in my Desktop), I was able to install without issue.

Give that a try and see if it works for you.

Edit: Be sure to delete all previous failed installations if any exist.

Comment: I tried this way but unfortunately it didn't work for me. I solved it by installing pgAdmin separately from the postgreSQL installer. I know it sounds odd and not relevant to the problem I had. Maybe I did something else as well since I tried so many things to make this work haha :D But yes, that was the solution for me. Still, thank you for your suggestion and answer!

Comment: I'm not quite sure then...I'm on the latest version of Big Sur. I wasn't doing a combined install with PgAdmin however. I use DBeaver preferably. I was using the installer from EDB for the latest Mac OS version. https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads. Glad to hear you were able to work around it.