# How to install PostgreSQL 14 into MacOS Big Sur

Tags: postgresql, macos-big-sur, pgadmin-4

I am currently self-studying postgreSQL from the ground up. I have spent the last 3 days trying to install PostgreSQL 14 and pgAdmin 4 into Mac OS Big Sur (version 11.6.2), but I kept getting the following errors:

**1.** When running pgAdmin 4, I encountered this message at the very beginning:

[image]

**2.** When installing postgreSQL 14 from [EDB](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads), at the very end of the installation process, I kept bumping into the error message: *Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly Failed to start the database server.* I tried following the solutions suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66061281/postgresql-installation-fails-with-macos-big-surm1), but I still get the same error in **1**.

**Question.** Can someone please help me with the entire installment process to overcome these errors? Also, I am curious to know if pgAdmin 4's role to PostgreSQL 14 is the same as Rstudio's role to R or Anaconda to Python?

Comment: For you use case I would suggest 1) Uninstall the EDB package 2) From here [MacOS downloads](https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/) [Postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com/).

Comment: `pgAdmin4` is just a GUI client for Postgres. I would suggest learning to use the `psql`  command  line client that comes with Postgres.

Comment: Or use homebrew.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: I uninstalled everything already, and then kept installing the first choice in your link but got the above error. Which option do you suggest me to install? I tried Postgres.app, but I have no idea how to start importing a database into it so that I can try out some simple `SQL` statements (e..g. `SELECT * from [ABC]`). Can you please provide further help?

Comment: @kometen: to me, using homebrew is a maze...I seriously hate dealing with command line. You know of any good tutorials on how to get started with creating a database (or even better, importing an existing database) into `psql` so that I can jumpstart my SQL coding journey?

Comment: Now that you have the server installed you can use `psql` to run the commands listed here [SQL commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-commands.html). For instance to create a database: `CREATE DATABASE <db_name>` where `<db_name>` is replaced with the name of your choice.  Though from what you say, you need to find a good beginners introduction to SQL and databases and go through it before going too much farther. A quick search found [Postgresql tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/)